# How to run Apache Solr service from within Python

Tags: python, solr

I have successfully ran the example here: https://github.com/toastdriven/pysolr/ This requires that Solr is running locally by typing the following command into terminal (java -jar start.jar). My question is, can I start the service without using the terminal at all?

Comment: It can work on Tomcat or other web containers.

Comment: can you evolve a bit more?

Comment: [Official Doc](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat)

Comment: why do I have to install a web containers for doing that? is there any other way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr works using `http`. You would need a container that acts a web server. Solr comes with Jetty by default, so when you do a `java -jar start.jar`, Jetty kicks in internally.

The only way of embedding solr, AFAIK, is to use `EmbeddedSolrServer` as mentioned [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj#EmbeddedSolrServer). This works with Solrj, which is a Solr client for Java. I'm afraid there isn't anything similar for PySolr, to my knowledge.